# how to merge two ranges of numbers, in one?

Tags: c++, c++17

I can't cope with one task. I'm standing in front of a red wall. There are lasers between me and the wall. If he fires a missile and it hits the red wall, the lasers will turn off. My task is to write an algorithm that will find all the safe bands where I can fire the projectile so that it does not hit any laser.
Data:

- the width of the corridor on which I am standing is the size of the table 'y'.
- The index of the array is the y-coordinate of the first point, and the number in the array under this index is the second y-coordinate. Together they create a segment that is a laser

I've included a photo below to show what it looks like.

My algorithm doesn't work for one case. when the lasers are located along the X axis (I did not take the x coordinates into account in the algorithm, the y coordinates are enough for the solution.) Examples of data on which the algorithm crashes are provided in the code.

Algorithm returned table [0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,11]. And he should return [0,1,1,3,3,11]. Instead of the band (1,3), the algorithm returns two separate bands (1,2), (2,3). I don't know how to make the program merge them into one. Please help

[image]

```
int main() {
    int y[] = {0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0};
    int result[22];
    int idx=0;
    int licznik=0;
    bool free = false;

    for(int i=0; i<22; i++)
    {
        result[i]=0;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        if(y[i]>0 && i!=y[i])
        {
            i=y[i]-1;
            free = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if(y[i+1]==0 && free==false && i!=y[i])
            {
                free = true;
                result[idx] = i;
                idx++;
                licznik++;
            }
            else if(free == true && y[i+1]==0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(free == true && y[i+1]!=0)
            {
                free = false;
                result[idx] = i+1;
                idx++;
                licznik++;
            }
            else
            {
                result[idx] = i;
                idx++;
                result[idx] = i+1;
                idx++;
                licznik+=2;
            }
        }
    }

    if(licznik%2 == 1)
    {
        result[idx] = 11;
    }
```

Comment: It is a well-known problem of merging overlapping intervals. TL;DR create a sorted list of  start and end points. Traverse it, increasing a counter each time you find a start point and decreasing it each time you find an end point.